# How to allow a special character in a regex search pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm retrieving a search pattern from an excel file which is the base name for multiple other files, i'm then retrieving all those other files and trying to match the files with the base name.

So let say the base name is `328.pdf`. It be can anything except a space character.
Then the files, for example `./Input\32581.pdf` and `./Input\32896.pdf` would be matched.

I have managed this so far:

```
regex = new Regex($@".*({data[i, j]})(.[^\s]*)(\.pdf?)\w+");
var matchingFiles = PdfFiles.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).ToList();`
```

But it fails for the `backslash` before the file name, and i couldn't find how to include it in the search pattern. Any help is appreciated.

The `data[i, j]` is the base name.

Comment: `Regex.Escape`.

Comment: C# does have an anoying habit of requiring you to escape the escape characters in this kind of thing.